# Sum of finite series of $\exp(an^2 + bn + c))$

Tags: summation, exponential-sum

Is there a way to simplify that sum to an expression without actual performing the summation, similar to the formula for calculating the sum of a (finite) geometric series?

$\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} \exp(an^2 + bn + c)$

Note that $a\neq0$

Comment: If $a=0$, it *is* geometric. Don't know about the other case, don't see how it can be simplified. I should point out that "$i$" is an unfortunate choice for the index name in this context. It took a moment for me to realize you weren't meaning $\sqrt{-1}$...

Comment: You are right, the choice of i was a bad idea, replaced it with n. Unfortunately, a is not 0.

Comment: I've been thinking about this a good bit. I'm working on trying to add/subtract terms to make sequential families of geometric series that could be summable. You've got me obsessed with this now -- thanks a lot ;) Seriously, there may be some hope, will keep looking at it. Please post if you come upon something yourself. Good luck!

Comment: Haha, you're welcome! I will let you know if I come up with something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the [Jacobi theta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function), which knows no closed form. For instance, $\displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty a^{n^2}=\theta_3(0,a)$.

Comment: See also the *Wolfram Math World* [article](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiThetaFunctions.html) on this subject.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the answer is no. Firstly, the class of formulae that we can sum is quite small, and the vast majority of them have no general closed form. Secondly, Wolfram does not know how to sum $a^{n^2}$ which is quite discouraging. Thirdly, using discrete calculus reveals a very erratic rate of growth. It's rare that closed forms exist that neither wolfram nor discrete calc can detect.